# Terraform and AWS spots instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

As described in https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17429
After 7 days the spot request is getting cancelled and the instance is still running. So when I run the "terraform apply" its trying to create a new spot. This happens with AWS provider >=1.13.0.

I'm using AWS provider 1.32.0, does anyone know a workaround to this issue? on future installation I will use the valid_until flag which will extend the request lifetime, but what about already installed spots?

Thanks

```
resource "aws_spot_instance_request" "cheap_worker" {
  count = "${var.kube_master_spot_num}"
  ami = "${data.aws_ami.nat_ami.id}"
  availability_zone  ="${element(slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names,var.kube_master_on_demand_num,var.availability_zones_num),count.index)}"
  spot_price    = "3"
  instance_type = "${var.kube_master_type}"
  subnet_id = "${element(module.aws-vpc.aws_subnet_ids,count.index + var.kube_master_on_demand_num)}" # adjusting to a case with spots & on-demand servers
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ "${module.aws-vpc.cluster_sg_id}", "${module.aws-vpc.route53_sg_id}" ]
  key_name = "${basename(var.local_ssh_key)}"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  root_block_device = [{volume_type="gp2",volume_size="50",delete_on_termination=true}]
  spot_type = "one-time"
  wait_for_fulfillment = true

  tags {
    Name = "${var.kube_identify}-${var.kube_type}-master-${count.index}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "sleep 120"
  }
  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file(var.local_ssh_key)}"
  }
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo apt-get update"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the Terraform code you are using to create the spot instances? Is there a reason you don't want to create one time requests instead of persistent requests? I think that might be causing this behaviour.

Comment: code is attached. I using "one-time" requests.

Comment: Have you tried using the `valid_until` command?  https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_instance_request.html

Comment: sure....I have mentioned this in my question